# Closed form expression for the sum of $i^a (n-i)^b$ from $0$ to $n$

Tags: summation, closed-form, bernoulli-numbers

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$.

It's [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) that we have
$$
\int_0^v x^a (v-x)^b\,dx = \frac{a!\, b!}{(a+b+1)!} v^{a+b+1} = \frac{v^{a+b+1}}{(a+b+1){a+b \choose a}}
$$

There's also [closed sum expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) of sorts for $\sum_{i=0}^n i^a$ (expressing it as a polynomial on $n$ of degree $a+1$ with Bernoulli numbers involved in the coefficients) known as “Faulhaber's formula”.

Is there a similar closed form expression for the following sum?
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n i^a (n-i)^b
$$

To be a bit clearer about what I mean by “closed form”, a sum with a number of terms dependent on $a$ and $b$ is of course acceptable, because the result is clearly a polynomial of degree $a+b+1$ in $n$, but the goal is to no longer have sums involving $n$.